# How can I reduce the width of an HtmlTableCell or otherwise join together two controls in an HtmlTableRow?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am dynamically creating several HtmlTableRows and adding cells to them, like so:

```
HtmlTable dynamicTable = new HtmlTable();

. . .

// Create row 6
var row6 = new HtmlTableRow();
var cellLitCtrl_6 = new HtmlTableCell();
var cellTxtbx_6 = new HtmlTableCell();
row6.Cells.Add(cellLitCtrl_6);
row6.Cells.Add(cellTxtbx_6);
var mailStopStr = new Label
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-label",
    Text = "Mail Stop:"
};
cellLitCtrl_6.Controls.Add(mailStopStr);

boxMailStop = new TextBox
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-input"
};
cellTxtbx_6.Controls.Add(boxMailStop);
dynamicTable.Rows.Add(row6);

// Create row 7
var row7 = new HtmlTableRow();
var cellCkbx_7 = new HtmlTableCell();
var cellLitCtrl_7 = new HtmlTableCell();
var cellTxtbx_7 = new HtmlTableCell();
row7.Cells.Add(cellCkbx_7);
row7.Cells.Add(cellLitCtrl_7);
row7.Cells.Add(cellTxtbx_7);

CheckBox ckbxEmployeeQ = new CheckBox
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-input",
    ID = "ckbxEmp",
};
ckbxEmployeeQ.Text = "Employee?";
cellCkbx_7.Controls.Add(ckbxEmployeeQ);

var SSNOrITINStr = new Label
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-label",
    Text = "ITIN:",
    ID = "lblSSNOrITIN"
};
cellLitCtrl_7.Controls.Add(SSNOrITINStr);

boxSSNOrITIN = new TextBox
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-input",
    ID = "txtbxSSNOrITIN",
    Width = 80,
    MaxLength = 12
};
cellTxtbx_7.Controls.Add(boxSSNOrITIN);
dynamicTable.Rows.Add(row7);
```

This code produces what you see here:

[image]

But I want the textbox (the yellow one) to be snug up against its label ("SSN" in the screamshot, but it can also be "ITIN" depending on the state of the "Employee?" checkbox).

So what we have here is an HtmlTableRow with two elements (the "Mail Stop:" label and its "associated" Textbox) and another HtmlTableRow with three elements (the checkbox, label, and textbox).

The second HtmlTableRow is obviously taking its layout cue from the one above (aligning cells to to the same X coordinate value), but why? And how can I circumvent that? I want the second row to look like this:

```
|_| Employee?   SSN |___________|
```

...not like this:

```
|_| Employee?   SSN              |___________|
```

How can I "snug up" the label ("SSN") and the following Textbox?

I tried putting the label and textbox in the same HtmlTableCell, but it blew up at runtime when I tried to add two Controls to a single HtmlTableCell.

For the most part, it's nice that the supposedly "independent" HtmlTableRows horizontally line up with each other, but I don't know why/how they do that, nor how to bypass that usually-desirable feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlTableCell seems to have a ColSpan property.  You may try setting that on the other rows to format it the way you would like:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablecell.colspan(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That got my hopes up, but it does nothing (good); I first set the ColSpan for the cell with the label to 12, which made matters worse - the textbox went even further afield (to the right); then I tried ColSpans of 1, then 0, then -1, and none of those were any better than the original (as shown in the screamshot). Finally, I tried -42, as 42 is supposed to be the answer to everything, but -42 seems to be (perhaps logically) the answer to nothing.

Comment: Hey, I think you would want to increase the colspan of the row above the employee SSN row.  So, the mailstop textbox cell should have a colspan of 2.  That would make it span over the employee SSN's label and textbox cell.

I see that you posted another answer though.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer to my specific question (I didn't find a way to do that), but this is the solution I ended up with: adding these controls to the page not as part of a table, but "standalone":

```
// These elements were not aligning right as row 7 of the section 1 table, so I am just adding them one by one
CheckBox ckbxEmployeeQ = new CheckBox
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-input",
    ID = "ckbxEmp",
};
ckbxEmployeeQ.Text = "Employee?";
this.Controls.Add(ckbxEmployeeQ);

AddVerticalSpace();

var SSNOrITINStr = new Label
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-label",
    Text = "ITIN:",
    ID = "lblSSNOrITIN"
};
SSNOrITINStr.Style.Add("padding", "2px");
this.Controls.Add(SSNOrITINStr);

boxSSNOrITIN = new TextBox
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-input",
    ID = "txtbxSSNOrITIN",
    Width = 80,
    MaxLength = 12
};
this.Controls.Add(boxSSNOrITIN);

AddVerticalSpace();
```